# Prove using the definition of limit $\lim_{(x, y)\to (0, 0)}\frac{4x^3y - x^4y^5 + 14}{7 - xy}=2$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I've been trying for a while to prove $$\lim_{(x, y)\to (0, 0)}\frac{4x^3y - x^4y^5 + 14}{7 - xy}=2$$, but I don't even know how to continue after $|\lim_{(x, y)\to (0, 0)}\frac{4x^3y - x^4y^5 + 2xy}{7 - xy}|$. Any hints or solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Subtract 2 to get rid of the 14.

Then, for $|x|, |y| < 1$, $|7-xy| > 6$
so the denominator is bounded away from zero.

Finally, if $|x|, |y| < c$,
see what bounds you can get on the expression.

Comment: How can I make a formal proof out of this?

Answer (score 0):

The function is continuous at the point (0,0) so you can literally just plug in the values (0,0)

$ \begin{array}{l}
f( x,y) =\frac{4x^{3} y-x^{4} y^{5} +14}{7-xy}\\
\lim _{(x,y)\rightarrow ( 0,0)}\left[\frac{4x^{3} y-x^{4} y^{5} +14}{7-xy}\right] =f( 0,0) =\frac{4( 0)^{3} \cdot 0-( 0)^{4}( 0)^{5} +14}{7-( 0)( 0)} =\frac{14}{7} =2
\end{array}$

I'm not familiar with this kind of a limit, so maybe I'm wrong, but I believe regular rules apply to this limit.

Someone tell me if my method is incorrect though.

Comment: You need to prove that $f$ is continuous at $0,0$. To prove this, one of the things you need to show is that the limit at that point is equal to the function.

Comment: Plugging in the values directly doesn't end up in an indeterminant form, so that means that the function is continuous at that point does it not?

Comment: It absolutely does not! For a function to be continuous at $a$ you need $f(a) = \lim_{x \to a} f(x)$. A counterexample to your argument would be $f(x) = x^2 \text{ if } x \ne 2$ and $5$ otherwise. Not having an indeterminate form doesn't mean continuous!!

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{(x, y)\to (0, 0)}|\frac{4x^3y - x^4y^5 + 2xy}{7 - xy}|$$

$$|\frac{4x^3y - x^4y^5 + 2xy}{7 - xy}|=|xy||\frac{4x^2 - x^3y^4 + 2}{7 - xy}| < \epsilon$$

So $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} < \delta$, so $|x|<\delta$ and $|y|<\delta$

Choose a $\delta \le 1$. So $|x|,|y|<1$. So what's an upper bound M for $|4x^2-x^3y^4+2|$ and what's an upper bound N for $|\frac{1}{7-xy}|$?

You want $|xy|MN < \epsilon$. so $|xy|< \frac{\epsilon}{MN}$

Now you can do your epsilon delta proof using $\delta = \min\{1,\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{MN}}\}$